# Regex to remove iframe with facebook but keeps youtube

Tags: php, regex

I want to remove only iframe(and everyhing inside iframe)with facebook like above but to keep youtube iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F%3Fp%313098&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=500&amp;action=recommend&amp;colorscheme=light" ></iframe>
```

To keep iframes from youtube:

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/hiYtWYLEjlI?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I've this regex but it only remove

```
<\/*i(?:frame|layer)|l(?:ayer|ink)[^>]*+>
```

https://regex101.com/r/eM9eS3/5

Comment: Can you add samples of what you want to remove and what you want to let?

Comment: I think [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/eM9eS3/7) will do the job. It checks for presence of `www.facebook.com` in your `<iframe>` and matches it.

Comment: @noob Yes works! :) Еxactly what I was looking for.Thanks noob! Put as answer to vote!

Comment: I have added additional example and posted it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are roughly trying to check if `www.facebook.com` is present in `<ifram>` or not. This can be achieved by using following regex.

**Regex:** `(?=.*www\.facebook\.com.*)<iframe .*<\/iframe>`

**Explanation:**

- `(?=.*www\.facebook\.com.*)` checks for presence of `www.facebook.com` between the `<iframe>` tags.

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eM9eS3/8)**</kbd>

Comment: This will break if the iframes aren't separated by a newline `\n` character.

Comment: @JamesBuck: Yes it does. I assumed OP only wants to match without breaking the line.

Answer (score 6):

Better take the `xpath` approach:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($your_html_string);
$iframes = $xml->xpath("//iframe[contains(@src, 'facebook.com')]");
```

And delete these:

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($iframes);$i++) {
    $iframe = $iframes[$i];
    unset($iframe[0][0]);
}
```

Your new XML looks like:

```
echo $xml->asXML();
```

As whole function:

```
function goAwayFacebook($html) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($html);
    $iframes = $xml->xpath("//iframe[contains(@src, 'facebook.com')]");
    for ($i=0;$i<count($iframes);$i++) {
        $iframe = $iframes[$i];
        unset($iframe[0][0]);
    }
    return $xml->asXML();
}

$newhtml = goAwayFacebook($html);
```

Comment: This is more difficult!

Comment: @1mnumb1: I thought you were looking for a solution that flawlessly works :)

Comment: Can I make this as function ?

Comment: @1mnumb1: Sure, why not?

Comment: I need to implement into smarty! Can you help with function?

Comment: @1mnumb1: There you go. Might need to change the function name though :)

Comment: @Jan at least it's descriptive ;)

Comment: `goAwayFacebook` <- this is awesome :D

Comment: @noob: Might need a break :)

Comment: @Jan Thanks bro :) Yeaaah me too liked function name :)